# Why shell is not part of RTOS code?

Tags: shell, rtos

I see many RTOSs (Ex Nuttx) have the shell as an application.

Is it just a convention in RTOS to keep the not-so important code outside RTOS to minimize the code size?
Is n't shell part of OS in Linux?
Why shouldn't shell be inside the OS code as a module like memory manager, etc?
If I move the shell code inside RTOS to be part of RTOS & inited & launched like any other RTOS module, will there be any problem?

Comment: Maybe you're confusing the term OS in general with the kernel.  OS means Operating System, and this may be as large or as small as one needs it to be for a particular application.  Embedded devices, for example, often come with no console functionality or ability to launch user applications.  So, there is no need for shell by default.   All OS, however, have at least some type of kernel (a 'heart' if you will) that does all the task coordination, etc.  Putting optional OS parts together with required ones would make the minimum memory requirements larger than necessary for many applications.

Comment: @tonypdmtr : Good *answer* - shame you posted it as a *comment*.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it just a convention in RTOS to keep the not-so important code
> outside RTOS to minimize the code size?

It is not a matter of convention, nor is it to do with "importance".  The RTOS vendor/author is hardly in a position to determine what is important in your embedded application.  RTOS are not normally true "full operating systems", but are just a deterministic real-time thread or process scheduler with IPC, timing, and synchronisation services.  They do one thing well, and everything else is down to the application developer.  Moreover most RTOS are no more than static link libraries used to build a single monolithic multi-threaded application rather than an OS that can dynamically load, execute and terminate processes.  So in this sense any shell provided is not a separate application as you suggest, but a separate library component and at runtime a separate thread or task.

Moreover a typical embedded application runs on custom hardware often with tight memory constraints, so an RTOS must often be minimal or scalable so that it contains only what is necessary to the embedded application and nothing more.  Where "middleware" such as filesystems, networking, USB, command shell etc. are required they are typically provided by third-party libraries or add-on components, and run as threads rather then in the kernel; because again it is the application developer who determines what tasks are real-time critical and must preempt any other operation.  So it is also about having complete scheduling control.

> Isn't shell part of OS in Linux?

It is not part of the Linux *kernel* (and Linux is no RTOS).  Most Linux distributions include a shell, and the nature of Linux is such that some form of shell is necessary or at least convenient for debug, configuration, and maintenance.  But Linux is hardly comparable; a minimal "lightweight" distribution requires around 4Mb of ROM and 16Mb of RAM to barely boot, while a typical RTOS kernel needs < 4Kb ROM and very little RAM.

> Why shouldn't shell be inside the OS code as a module like memory manager, etc?
> If I move the shell code inside RTOS to be part of RTOS & inited & launched like any other RTOS module, will there be any problem?

It is not clear what you mean by "inside the RTOS", and what you can do in any particular case would be specific to that product. Where the RTOS is a static library, there is no inside or outside the RTOS, it is all one application.  In side the RTOS *kernel* - the part that performs the scheduling - that makes little sense.

All the above describes a typical RTOS.  Products vary considerably in what they include, but most are highly scalable.  Products such a FreeRTOS or uC/OS-II for example are no more then scheduling kernels, while eCOS, QNX, and VxWorks are to varying extents more complete OSes including filesystem, shell, networking components and in some cases a clear device driver architecture, and even in some cases a POSIX API.